# Remove pattern from social media specific string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some strings from social media that I need to clean up. Every now and then the following pattern appears in the strings:

```
Pattern = 'Quote:\nOriginally Posted by username_xy  View Post'
```

What is the best way to check the strings to remove this pattern when a match occurs?

(the username in the pattern may vary)

Comment: which part of this string do you need to be cleaned?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that this is a snippet of an string. This pattern can generally occur at any position within a string and should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if this works for you

```
import re

regex = r"Quote:\sOriginally[\s]+Posted[\s]+by[\s]+[\w]+[\s]+View[\s]+Post"
re.sub(regex, '', 'Quote:\nOriginally Posted by username_xy  View Post' )
```